# Relation between .wlapp and .apk in worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have deployed my .wlapp and adapters in worklight server of version 1.0. Now i have 2.0 version with me and added some additional functionality. Now I updated only adapter in my server. Installed 2.0 apk in mobile. Now Apk have some additional html files and css which does not have in wlapp 1.0. If I access application from mobile new functionality will work or not.

Comment: Please describe your problem in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an app that is v1.0, you will also have a .wlapp v1.0 file and an .apk v1.0 file.
if you create a v2.0 of your app, you will also have a .wlapp v2.0 file and an .apk v2.0.

The .wlapp file contains metadata needed for the server to recognize an app as v2.0, and you deploy it to the Worklight Server.

The .apk file is the actual resulting app and you submit it to the App Store/Google Marketplace/etc...

Note that if you only change web resources you can also opt to remain in v1.0 and [use Direct Update to update just the web resources](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/admin/c_direct_updates_app_versions_to_mob.html) of your Worklight application.